# ReactJS - Do not render until component is above page fold (within visible window area)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading

**Scenario**

I'm working on a ReactJS project that has a lot of re-used components on the page, so many components that it causes some of the css animations to become sluggish. I've found that if I use `display:none` on components below the page fold that my performance bottlenecks vanish.

**Question**

Is there a currently library, or a very simple way to accomplish this? Worst case I will write a library for this and put it on github.

**Caveats**

- Using `display:none` gives an element 0 width / height so I'll need to use a placeholder of an assumed size.
- I will "unrender" visible components once they go out of the visible window area
- lazy loading libs didn't pan out like I hoped, LazyLoadJS is the most promising and what I would leverage if I ultimately need to write my own solution

Comment: [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) should do the trick

Comment: You can check this out: [react-intersection-observer](https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My situation is rather unique but I'll break it down to relevant pieces as much as I can:

- My application is a ReactJS SPA or Single Page Application (so lots of xhr, async loading)
- Using the same scroll area for the entire life cycle (`.content-group`)

Json from the CMS includes component names and respective data. My "SomeFactory" (not the real name) gets the mapped component name and renders the component to the factory container.

Some Caveats:

- `forceCheck` is what made this work, it reassess where lazy items are within the scroll container
- `overflow` was helpful since I'm using `overflow: hidden` as part of this element's ancestry.

**Code**

```
import LazyLoad, { forceCheck } from 'react-lazyload';

class LazyLoadOptimized extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <LazyLoad throttle={50} height={200} offset={400} overflow scrollContainer={'.content-group'}>
                {this.props.children}
            </LazyLoad>
        )
    }
}

export default class SomeFactory extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate() {
        forceCheck();
    }
}
```